# Jasmine SpecRunner style page for Karma

Tags: jasmine, gulp, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, gulp-watch

I am trying to show Jasmine SpecRunner style page using karma-jasmine, karma and gulp plugins but not able to see all the specs listing all of the test that passed on failed. I used karma-jasmine-reporter node module to get a report of the tests that ran but how can I rerun an individual test. I am looking to generate a page like this where I can see the result and rerun individual tests.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found that https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jasmine-html-reporter the karma-jasmine-html-reporter is the best UI reporter that gets close to the default jasmine html file look.

Your question is old, but it's what I was trying to find myself.
If you found a better solution since posting I'd like to know. One thing that this HTML reporter doesn't do is refresh if you updated the tests.

So if you run 'karma start' then it will run the tests, open your browser then you have to click on the debug button to show the UI reporting of your tests.
Then if you update the tests, the cmd window will refresh to reflect your new tests but the browser window will not.  You must refresh it manually.  Would be awesome to not have to do that.